# Show that first order Chebyshev polynomials are in fact polynomials

Tags: generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Given the 1st order Chebyshev polynomials
$$
G(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} T_n(x) t^n = \frac{1-tx}{1-2xt+t^2}
$$

I'm wondering how can I show that $T_n(x)$ are polynomials ?

Comment: You're not given the 1st order Chebyshev polynomials. You're given the generating function for the 1st order Chebyshev polynomials. Multiply by $1-2xt+t^2$, collect with respect to $t$, and compare LHS and RHS.

Comment: I get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T_n(x) [t^n - 2xt^{n+1} + t^{n+2}] = 1-tx$

Comment: Write out this sum for $n=0,1$. What can you deduce about $T_0(x)$ and $T_1(x)$?

Comment: I get $T_1(x)[t - 2xt^2 + t^3] + T_2(x)[t^2 - 2xt^3 + t^4] + ... = 1 - tx$. 
I honestly don't know what should I deduce about $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

This just elaborates the hint given by @RandyMarsh.
$$1-xt=(1-2xt+t^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n(x)t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n(x)t^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2xT_n(x)t^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n(x)t^{n+2}\\=T_0(x)+T_1(x)t+\sum_{n=2}^\infty T_n(x)t^n-2xT_0(x)t-\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2xT_{n-1}(x)t^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty T_{n-2}(x)t^n\\=T_0(x)+\big(T_1(x)-2xT_0(x)\big)t+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\big(T_n(x)-2xT_{n-1}(x)+T_{n-2}(x)\big)t^n.$$ Now compare the coefficients of $t^0$, $t^1$, and $t^n$ for $n\geqslant 2$. *And conclude using induction on $n$.*